# jquery - stop propagation to jQuery UI Tabs and follow link

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, stoppropagation

Apologies if this ask been asked before - I searched and didn't find anything that matched exactly what I'm seeing.

Here's the situation: I'm using jQuery UI Tabs for selection of images on a page. For one of the tabs, the desired result is to follow the link for that Tab, opening it a new *browser* tab (I'll try to keep the uses of the word "tab" straight here), and ignore the rest of the UI Tabs code. So essentially I want Tabs to create the visual Tab for selection but not do any of the usual jQuery processing that happens when one clicks on that particular Tab. For the other Tabs, the default UI Tabs behavior is fine.

What I figured I could do is attach an event to that Tab and call event.stopPropagation() which would prevent the bubbling to the UI code and then let it drop through and take the link (the click event for the tabs is on an 'a' tag). I do have it set up so that my event code is first in line, it executes before the UI code, and it prevents the UI code from running.

However, I see the following message in the console if I do that:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [link] (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

(Note: the link is to an interactive page in a different domain, which is the main reason I'm opening a new *browser* tab)

The new browser tab does not open and I'm left with that selected Tab with blank contents below.

If I do a "window.open" for the link before the stopPropagation and add event.preventDefault(), I do get the result of the page opening in a new browser tab, but still see the error message. As a result of some fat fingers, I also noticed that if I have an undefined function in the click event code that it also has the desired reaction.

Anyway, is there something stupid I'm not seeing here? Should I just be happy with a solution that gives me the resulting behavior but with the error message?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On further review, the jQuery UI event handlers are firing - which is why I end up with that particular Tab selected. The cross-origin error makes sense there as the "a" tag points out of my domain. So even though I called stopPropagation and isPropagationStopped is TRUE after that, the jQuery UI code still executes.

Answer (score 1):

So as I suspected I was going about this all wrong. Chalk it up to jQuery UI novice-ness.

The UI provides a beforeActivate() event which does exactly what I want. Within the function, I can check to see if the proposed new Tab has the class I assign to mean "jump to the link", do the window call to create the new browser tab, and then return false so that the UI knows I don't want the Tab activated. The function returns true otherwise.